# Is $S{(x)}$ will uniformly convergent on $[-1,1]$ ? True/false .

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Is $S(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^2 (1-x^2)^{n-1}$  will  uniformly convergent on $[-1,1]$ ?  True/false .

My attempt  : Yes ,  $S_n$ will uniformly convergent on $[-1,1]$ if i put $x = \frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ then by $M_n$ Test $||f||_{ \infty}=  \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n} (\frac{ n-1}{n})^{n-1}= \lim_{\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{e}=0$

Is its True ?

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks u

Comment: But $\sum_n 1/\sqrt n$ doesn't converge...

Comment: @Math1000  but  domain is  $[-1,1]$

Comment: Perhaps you meant to write $S(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty x^2(1 - x^2)^{n-1}$? Or $S_k(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^k x^2(1 - x^2)^{n-1}$?

Comment: Are you sure you quoted the question correctly? It makes little sense to write $S_n$ for a sum that doesn't depend on $n$ (because you're summing over all $n$) but does depend on $x$. Also, I don't see what your attempt (plugging in an arbitrary-looking value of $x$ that depends on $n$ and is therefore different for every term in the sum) has to do with the question, nor do I see what either @Math1000's comment or your comment has to do with your attempt.

Comment: @kobe u gots  the  logic     as  I was writing $S(x)$

Comment: Hint: The sum is a geometric series, so you can explicitly evaluate it in closed form. Note though that you have to treat $x=0$ differently from all the non-zero $x$'s.

Comment: @AndreasBlass  i have  edited

Comment: While the answer below settles the issue, computing the series by hand is trivial and gives a discontinuous function at $0$ so obviously we cannot have uniform convergence on any interval containing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$\sup_{x \in [-1,1]}\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty x^2(1-x^2)^{k-1}\right| \geqslant \sup_{x \in [-1,1]}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} x^2(1-x^2)^{k-1} \geqslant \sup_{x \in [-1,1]}nx^2(1-x^2)^{2n} $$

Take $x^2 = 1/(2n)$, that is $x = \pm1/\sqrt{2n} \in [-1,1]$, and it follows that

$$\sup_{x \in [-1,1]}\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty x^2(1-x^2)^{k-1}\right| \geqslant \frac{1}{2}\left(1 - \frac{1}{2n}\right)^{2n}$$

Since the limit of the RHS as $n \to \infty$ is $e^{-1}/2 \neq 0$ the convergence is not uniform on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: thanks @RRL but im not  getting why  u take $k= n+1 $?  as  according to the  question  its is given that $ k = 1$ to $\infty$

Comment: @jasmine:  Suppose the series is pointwise convergent as $\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(x) = S(x)$ for $x \in I$.  That means for each fixed $x$, $S_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n f_k(x)  \to S(x)$ as $n \to \infty$.  For uniform convergence we must have $\sup_{x}|S_n(x) - S(x)| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.  But $|S_n(x) - S(x)] = \sum_{k= n+1}^\infty f_k(x)$ -- which is the tail of the series.

Comment: thanks  u @RRL got its

Comment: @jasmine: You're welcome.